# I want to start learning physics

Tags: resource-recommendations, soft-question, education

I want to start learning physics, could you recommend books and/or other resources to get me started in this field?

I would also like you to tell me what things I should keep in mind before I start learning physics

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Fundamentals-Physics-Extended-David-Halliday/dp/1118230728/

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cw97Tj5zxvA

She has good advice. TL;DR: Pick an intro physics textbook used by a university intro physics course (search for course websites and you'll find this information) and then do lots and lots of problems.

Comment: Resources from a possible dupe: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/

Comment: Are you in high school or university? Have you learned calculus?

Comment: @Ghoster I'm not in college yet, I'm 16 years old, I haven't learned calculus yet

Comment: *I would also like you to tell me what things I should keep in mind before I start learning physics.* Learn calculus as soon as possible. Physics makes a lot more sense with calculus than without it.

Comment: Get proficient at geometry, trigonometry, algebra and the basics of differential/integral calculus (at first, be able to differentiate and integrate many simple functions). Without these basics, you can hardly speak the language of physics. Make sure you are completely familiar with working with vectors, this last cannot be emphasized enough. Most of the people who struggle with freshman college physics, struggle because their grounding in these basics is not good.